# nginx upstream 404 error, but work on redirect

Tags: nginx

I don't know why that upstream is not working.
It is working normally for the URL with "gitlabre" but it will long loading for "gitlab" then display 404 not find.
I haven't any idea on it......

```
upstream gitlab{
    server <server IP_address>:8086;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  ****.gitlab;
    location /gitlab/ {
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
    location /gitlabre/ {
        #work
        return 301 http://****.gitlab:8086/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to modify the iptables rules on your host to permit connections from Docker containers

```
#iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```